# Thread.Sleep into a Task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I've the following code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<int> threadsIds = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000);
        DateTime globalStart = DateTime.Now;

        Console.WriteLine("{0:s.fff} Starting tasks", globalStart);
        Parallel.ForEach(threadsIds, (threadsId) =>
        {
            DateTime taskStart = DateTime.Now;
            const int sleepDuration = 1000;
            Console.WriteLine("{1:s.fff} Starting task {0}, sleeping for {2}", threadsId, taskStart, sleepDuration);
            Thread.Sleep(sleepDuration);
            DateTime taskFinish = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("{1:s.fff} Ending task {0}, task duration {2}", threadsId, taskFinish, taskFinish- taskStart);

        });
        DateTime globalFinish= DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("{0:s.fff} Tasks finished. Total duration: {1}", globalFinish, globalFinish-globalStart);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Currently when I run it, it takes ~60seconds to run it. For what I understand, it's because .Net doesn't create one thread per task but some threads for all the `Tasks`, and when I do the `Thread.Sleep`, I prevent this thread to execute some other tasks.

In my real case, I've some work to do in parallel, and in case of failure, I've to wait some amount of time before trying again.

I'm looking something else than the `Thread.Sleep`, that would allow other tasks to run during the "sleep time" of other tasks.

Unfortunately, I'm currently running .Net 4, which prevent me to use `async` and `await`(which I guess could have helped me in this case.

Ps, I got the same results by:

- putting `Task.Delay(sleepDuration).Wait()`
- Not using `Parallel.Foreach`, but a foreach with a `Task.Factory.StartNew`

Ps2, I know that I can do my real case differently, but I'm very interessted to understand how it could be achieved that way.

Comment: `Task.Delay.Wait()` does (effectively) the same as `Thread.Sleep`, so it's clear why it doesn't help. The question seems to be more like "How to retry failed tasks?" then how to start the tasks at all. But I guess that retry part depends on your real code and requirements. The idea of having the tasks wait and retry will always lead to the same results you are describing. Try evaluating the result of each task and restarting the failed ones.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` is not for running all operations in parallel at the same time but rather to optimize execution to run *some* in parallel. `await Task.WhenAll`  + `await Task.Delay()` instead of `Parallel.ForEach` + `Thread.Sleep()` indeed would be a solution...

Comment: If you need to wait some time, why not use a Timer and have the failed task set the timer to run your method again in 60 seconds or whatever, like that you don't sleep in the threadpool.

Comment: You may want to look at [Task.ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991174(v=vs.100).aspx). This can be called with options so that the continuation will only be started if the first task failed. So your failed tasks could throw and thereby starting (the same method) again, though there would be still the problem of waiting a little. Sorry, can't bring this together to a qualified answer.

Comment: @J4N: If you're running on the desktop, you can use [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) to enable `async` and `await`.

Comment: @RenéVogt Lik I told in my PS2, I know doing it some other way around(and basically I already did), but I was interessted to know if there was some technical ways to achieve this goal.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Like I said, in .Net 4. Async/await are not available.

Comment: @eurotrash first, that not the subject if I could rework the whole code, the question is to see if it is possible to have a task with a sleep-like operation, that doesn't allow other tasks to benefit from this thread. Also, for me Timer are more for somethings that will repeat over time, not just some wait operation.

Comment: @J4N But you don't want to have a wait operation (that forces a thread to be tied up doing nothing), and what you've described *is* wanting to repeat something over time.  You should be using a timer here.

Answer (score -1):

You are on the right path. `Task.Delay(timespan)` is the solution for your problem. Since you cannot use `async/await`, you have to write a bit more code to achieve the desired result.

Think about using `Task.ContinueWith()` method, for example:

```
Task.Run(() => { /* code before Thread.Sleep */ })
.ContinueWith(task => Task.Delay(sleepDuration)
    .ContinueWith(task2 => { /* code after Thread.Sleep */ }));
```

Also you will need create a class to make local method variables accessible across subtasks.

If you want to create a task that will run polling every second some condition, you could try the following code:

```
Task PollTask(Func<bool> condition)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    PollTaskImpl(tcs, condition);
    return tcs.Task;
}

void PollTaskImpl(TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs, Func<bool> condition)
{
    if (condition())
        tcs.SetResult(true);
    else
        Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(_ => PollTaskImpl(tcs, condition));
}
```

Don't worry about creating new task every second - `ContinueWith` and `async/await` methods do the same thing internally.

Comment: Your first continuation is creating a `Task<Task>`.  You need to unwrap it, else the next continuation will execute right away when it shouldn't.

Comment: Fixed the problem, just wanted to write more beautyful code.

Comment: Like I said, you should really unwrap the task, as it is you're still creating a nested task here, making the result of running this a task that's harder to work work.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. The issue is that I need to do something WHILE some condition is not reached: if subTask!=succeeded then sleep 1sec and start again. I don't see how it would be possible with this kind of continueWith

Comment: That's a *super* poor implementation.  You're creating *tons* of unnecessary requests to thread pool threads, creating tons of unnecessary tasks, and is extremely convoluted, entirely unnecessarily.

Comment: @J4N If that's what you want to do then *you should be asking that in your question*.  That's not what your question is asking, so you should not expect that to be what the answers answer.

Comment: @Servy, Nothing will change with `while (!condition()) await Task.Delay(1000);`. The framework will run a new task every time when a continuation resumes.

Comment: @AndreyNasonov You're using *three* on every iteration around the loop, instead of the one that is needed.

Comment: @Servy, The first task is scheduled in `Task.Run`, the second task in `ContinueWith`. Where is the third one? Anyway, you are right, `Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(...))` can be simplified to `Task.Delay(...)`. See the corrected version with only one task creation at every iteration.

Comment: @AndreyNasonov, small tweak: `Task.Run` was introduced in .NET 4.5. The question is about .NET 4.0, hence only `Task.Factory.StartNew` is available

Comment: @Servy I agree, sorry, I wanted to simplify the question and I tought that the question I put was representing my case. Sorry